# Why is constructing PDO connection slow?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using PDO in my PHP application. It connects to a MySQL server on the same server:

```
$db = new PDO(mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test, $username, $password);
```

I created two pages with the same output (just some dummy data in plain html) one of which contains the call to create PDO. If I open the page that uses no connection the response is between 0.5 and 1 second quicker.

Comment: How do you get data from a database without a connection?

Comment: The dummy data is just some plain HTML, nothing from the database.

Comment: That effect is not normal. Seems like you have server-related issues. Maybe SQL server is slow to respond. Try to investigate more, but to me this seems more like ServerFault problem.

Comment: See also $host=gethostbyname('localhost') at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16233679/1854563

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I've been doing some googling, and after reading [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/1064342), I changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. That solves the problem....

Comment: You made my day! Using localhost it took a whole second to connect, using 127.0.0.1 it takes about one millisecond.

Comment: Very helpful research. I tried to find the solution for while until this helped. Dropped from 1s to less than 3ms.

Comment: A little 'why': By using a hostname, PHP is forced to do a lookup in the DNS table (slow!). If this is a big table, it can take a long time before the entry is found. By using a static IP address you can skip this resolving altogether. You can even do this in production with non-localhost IP's!

Comment: DNS is slow, but not THAT slow.  There must be something else at play here.  Same happened for me 1sec down to ms.  Thanks for posting, very helpful

Comment: @AshMcConnell Would you happen to be using Windows 8? I believe it's an issue in Windows 8.

Comment: Using Win7x64 I've had the same issue- only a 21sec delay(!) Beware of localhost...