# system.db.CDbConnection taking more than 1 second to execute in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am a new to yii although i have worked a lot with codeigniter and was just trying to convert my code from codeigniter to yii
But the CDbconnection is taking more than 1 second to execute i have attached a screenshot.
also the sql code i am using.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = "total_photos";

$data = array( 'Gallerys' => Gallerynames::model()->findAll($criteria));
```

Please look into it[image: Screen shot of the log]

**Edit:**

Here is my db config

```
'db'=>array(
        'class' => 'system.db.CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yiiwiki',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'enableProfiling' => true,
        'schemaCachingDuration' => 3600,
    ),
```

Comment: also same thing in codeigniter is taking less than 0.004 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/final.deployment#enabling-schema-caching)

> Because ActiveRecord relies on the metadata about tables to determine
>   the column information, it takes time to read the metadata and analyze
>   it. This may not be a problem during development stage, but for an
>   application running in production mode, it is a total waste of time if
>   the database schema does not change.

so set the [schemaCachingDuration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#schemaCachingDuration-detail) of the [db](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#db-detail) application component a value greater than zero.
    'db'=>array(
                'class'=>'system.db.CDbConnection',
                'connectionString'=>'sqlite:/wwwroot/blog/protected/data/blog.db',
                'schemaCachingDuration'=>3600,
            ),

Keep in mind that you should specify a valid [cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#cache-detail) in the application config

**EDIT**
It seems your problem is not due to the schema. Refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800577/why-is-constructing-pdo-connection-slow) changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` will fix it

Comment: if you check out the time at which the log messages were posted, you can see that _opening_ the connection takes long, not _reading_ the schema. see the 2nd and 3rd row of messages in the pic.

Comment: Ya i am also talking about the same that connection is taking longer

Comment: Applied what you said still no improvement.

Comment: oh my mistake. Btw changing the 'localhost' in connection string to '127.0.0.1' makes any difference?

Comment: Ya thank that was the solution this was also suggested by a guy on the forum thanks