# Yii $connection = Yii::app()->db is slow

Tags: mysql, database, yii

I have a fresh "installation" of yii with a mysql database in the background.

If i want to get the db connection from the app:

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
```

it needs about 1 second to this.

Is there any trick to speed it up?

Comment: Connecting to a database requires some time to establish. Usually applications have a database handle pool to recycle them between requests. What does Yii do for this?

Comment: This doesn't have to do with Yii, but rather with the particulars of your connection to the database.

Comment: I am sure it can't be 1 sec, it is very much high time, we get results below 1 sec..please debug correctly there may be another code that is taking high time.

Comment: The answer is here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800577/why-is-constructing-pdo-connection-slow/9800798#9800798

Comment: Mario S Fallen has the answer. It's not yii, rather your DNS table is the culprit. Change db host to 127.0.0.1 from localhost. Works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Debug to find the time used in Connecting to a database.

Test it using [WebGrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/).

I have tested it takes around 10ms for my case.