# What is the Symfony firewall doing that takes so long?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.2

My Symfony page isn't too slow (it loads in about 400 ms) but considering the fact that it's just a simple hello world page with basic authentication, it should be loading in less than 100 ms. When I enter the profiler, I see this:

[image: Profiler timeline]

Notice it just says "Firewall" for 250 ms. I thought the firewall was just responsible for keeping users out of certain areas of the page - I can't imagine that taking any longer than a few milliseconds plus the time it takes to fetch the user information from the database (which in this case is 61 ms).

Could somebody explain what the firewall actually does? If you have any general pointers on how to increase the firewall performance as well that would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Note**: I have Googled this of course, and I want to specify up front that I'm connecting to the MySQL database by IP address, not host name. This seemed to be the issue for every other case of slow Symfony firewall I could find.

---

Some resources from my project that could be relevant:

- [security.yaml](http://pastebin.com/sZG4whqD)
- [routing.yaml](http://pastebin.com/YUEqrmCc)
- [Astrups/SpectacleBundle/Entity/User.php](http://pastebin.com/wZHSy9Lq)
- [Astrups/SpectacleBundle/Service/Sha1Salted.php](http://pastebin.com/Wt5yFHhc)

Comment: I'd guess is executing all the rules in security.yml, the providers, acess control, and firewalls sections can get pretty nasty, checking all those for every request is time consuming.

Comment: @xr09: 251 ms is a *really* long time though (in computer time). I can't see any way simply reading the cached configuration and applying it to the security context could take anywhere near that long.

Comment: I've just noticed, your `Astrups/SpectacleBundle/Entity/User.php` breaks the **Single Responsibility Principle**.

Comment: Try use some profile. XDebug and XHProf are really good. Moreover there is bundle for the second one: https://github.com/jonaswouters/XhprofBundle. It'll let you figure out which method are the bottleneck

Comment: I'd love to hear why this question was down voted

Comment: Is this DEV or PROD build? Which version of Symfony2 have you?

Comment: @gatisl: Not sure what you mean by dev/prod build, but the page is just as fast whether I use "app.php" or "app_dev.php". I'm using Symphony 2.2.1.

Comment: @Codemonkey Yes, i meant prod/dev environments. Usually there is significant performance difference between both environments, because nothing is cached when dev environment is enabled.

Comment: have you try using other security provider and/or encoder?

Comment: Please check if you have APC installed.

Comment: @NHG: No APC installed. I'm just using vanilla Apache2 + PHP, freshly compiled. I'm currently trying to use XHProf to profile the firewall.

Comment: I too had a similar issue once until I noticed that I had a ajax request that was loading forever from the previous request and it was blocking the firewall

Comment: Can you post the request sequence for this. Was it (get '/' -> get 'login' -> post 'login_check' -> get '/') or something else. That will help define what state the security system was in during this request.

Comment: @james_t: That's the login sequence, yes, but the request I'm profiling is just for "/" after login.

Comment: @gatisl is right. Since you see the Profiler, you're in the DEV mode (app_dev.php). In this environment, no data is cached and additionally the profiler takes a while to load too.
Try to clear your PROD cache using: app/console cache:clear --env=prod and then visit your website in PROD mode (app.php). If you did right, you wont see the profiler anymore and the page will load faster.
More infos here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/configuration/environments.html

Comment: @MarcJuchli: As I commented earlier, I have tried both environments and can't tell any difference in speed. It takes about half a second in both. Once I log out and visit the login page though, the page loads amazingly fast (less than 100ms).

Comment: sorry didnt see this!
But this could also be an issue of dns lookup. See: http://12wiki.blogspot.ch/2012/11/why-does-symfony-2-firewall-take-so.html

Comment: @MarcJuchli: I also noted in the question that I'm connecting to the MySQL server by IP address if that's what you're referring to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alas, it turns out [Rawdreeg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2305403/rawdreeg) was *partly* right. I made a 20 line PHP script to profile how long it takes to connect to my MySQL server:

```
<?php

$time = microtime(true);

$con = new PDO(...);

$connect_time = microtime(true);

$result = $con->query('SHOW TABLES');

$query_time = microtime(true);

var_dump($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$time_con = ($connect_time - $time) * 1000;
$time_query = ($query_time - $connect_time) * 1000;

echo "Connection took $time_con ms\n";
echo "Query took $time_query ms\n";
```

The output was:

```
Connection took 230.18503189087 ms
Query took 64.532995223999 ms
```

Which fills the blanks of the Symfony profiler *perfectly*. The good news is that when my application goes live, it will connect to the MySQL server locally by socket, so it'll probably be blazing fast! There is little I can do about the speed during the development though, other than mirroring the MySQL server locally.

So to summarize the answer; the Symfony firewall initially creates the connection to the MySQL database, and in my case, that connection is quite slow. The MySQL connection time accounts for over 80% of the firewall's profiled time in my case.

---

**Note:** I'm already connecting to the MySQL server by IP address, and I've added `skip-name-resolve` to the MySQL configuration to no avail.

Comment: I have an app that isn't configured to use a database, same issue. I don't think this is the actual cause.

Comment: @guice It was in my case.

Answer (score 13):

I did some googling and I see that [this guy](http://12wiki.blogspot.com/2012/11/why-does-symfony-2-firewall-take-so.html), seems to have the answer to your question.

> After 15 minutes of research I ended up figuring out that this was due
>   to the PHP PDO constructor (my Firewall is the first to connect to the
>   database as I use Entities as users). With this knowledge the issue
>   was pretty quickly found ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800577/why-is-constructing-pdo-connection-slow), [[2]](http://drupal.org/node/1064342)): as it turns out
>   using a DNS name (like 'localhost') instead of an IP (like
>   '127.0.0.1') causes this issue.
>
> A simple edit of the parameters.yml file (changing localhost to
>   127.0.0.1) did the trick of reducing the Firewall load time to only a minimum.

Comment: For your information, [it's better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Since target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future.

Comment: I clearly specified in my question that this is **not** the issue. Check the **Note:** part.

Comment: woooow! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL server might be the problem. Try adding `skip-name-resolve` to the `[mysqld]` section of your `my.cnf` file. This stops MySQL from doing a reverse DNS lookup on the IP address of incoming connections.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check that out. But wouldn't connecting to MySQL go under "Doctrine" in the profiler?

Comment: I don't know. I was just going by the quote in Rawdreeg's answer that implies that the Firewall component is opening a/the database connection.

Comment: It didn't help unfortunately. Your answer did prompt me to write a script to profile the connection time though, which in turn answered my question.