# Symfony 3 - Firewall Listener Performance at Login

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-3.3

Replied to my own question and posted it here for reference to others.

---

## Setup

My application is really fast out of the box, running:

- `Symfony 3` with `Doctrine2`
- `PHP 5.6.*` with `CGI/FastCGI` as a PHP handler (not even php 7)
- `mySQL 5.6.*`

Then, it is optimised further with:

- `Zend OpCache` to get faster PHP execution through opcode caching and optimization
- `Memcached` to store `user sessions` in memcached
- `Memcached` to act as a `metadata cache driver` and a `query cache driver` for `doctrine 2`

## The bottleneck

However, one route is very slow and that is the `fos_user_security_check` route when I authenticate via the login form.

[image: Debug Profile Symfony3]
It shows `Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\FirewallListener` as the culprit - though I am not sure why that is because this route lights up quickly on my local machine but doesn't on my production machine.

### Things that I have tried

- [x] To use Memcached to cache PHP sessions -> no difference
- [x] To use Memcached to cache Doctrine stuff -> no difference
- [x] To run mysql with `skip-name-resolve` -> no difference

### Related posts I have seen

- [SecurityBundle Configuration ("security")](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#using-the-bcrypt-password-encoder)
- [What is the Symfony Firewall doing that takes so long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111324/what-is-the-symfony-firewall-doing-that-takes-so-long)
- [Why does the Symfony 2 firewall take so long to load?](http://12wiki.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/why-does-symfony-2-firewall-take-so.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two words!! "Encryption Algorithm".

```
There is a compromise between 'speed' and 'security'.
```

See [Using the pbkdf2 Encoder Security and Speed](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#using-the-pbkdf2-encoder-security-and-speed).

---

An example to show how 2 different encryption may affect speed.

<kbd>Configuration A:</kbd>

```
# Login in 3.5s in my case
security:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:

        # . Use `bcrypt` algorithm
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 13
```

<kbd>Configuration B:</kbd>

```
# Login in 400ms in my case
security:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
    # . Use `pdkdf2` algorithm
    algorithm:            pbkdf2
    hash_algorithm:       sha512
    encode_as_base64:     true
    iterations:           1000
    key_length:           40
```

Note, you will have to recreate your user in your database to test different encryption mechanisms.

---

This explains:

```
... this route lights up quickly on my local machine but doesn't on my production machine.
```

- My local machine has a `Intel Core i7-7820HQ @ 2.90GHz`
- My production machine has a `Intel Xeon E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz`

[image]