# Concurrent requests for Symfony4 REST API (LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle)

Tags: php, symfony4, restful-authentication, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm a bit lost right now and could use a push in the right direction.

#### In short

- PHP Symfony 4 project (mostly default configuration), hosted on Google Cloud App Engine
- REST API, authentication via [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle)
- Requests need to pass auth token on every request (Symfony firewall is `stateless: true`)
- Single Page Application as API consumer (React frontend)

In my use-case, one authenticated user opens page `X`. On this page, there are three different sections with data, that need to be loaded from the backend. Therefore, I have three API endpoints to be fetched.

When opening the page, these three requests aren't performed simultaniously, they wait for each other. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911808/symfony-not-serving-concurrent-requests) SO question there's already mentioned, that Symfony doesn't support concurrent requests for one user session or one could manually close an open session.
Since I'm not using sessions at all I don't want to mess with closing random stuff.

But my question:
I believe having a stateless API, where the user isn't stored in a server session. I have to pass the JWT token on every request.

-> Should it be possible having the three **authenticated** requests being served in parallel with a stateless REST API - or isn't it just not possible as soon as 'a user is involved'?

fyi: Trying three requests for an un-authed endpoints shows me parallel requests.

#### Code fragments

*security.yaml*

```
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/v1/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path:               /api/v1/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api/v1
            stateless: true
            access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/v1/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nevermind, it was a configuration problem with my Staging environment.
For the API endpoint I tested, a session was created.