# How can I change database connection "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, localhost, database-connection

According to the resolution of this question...

[What is the Symfony firewall doing that takes so long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111324/what-is-the-symfony-firewall-doing-that-takes-so-long)

...I try to change in the `.env` file

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost/project
```

to

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1/project
```

to achieve better performance.

But then I get an error:

> An exception occurred in driver:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
>
> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException:
>   "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection
>   refused" at
>   /Users/work/project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   line 112

Comment: try adding the used port number like `127.0.0.1:3306` and clear the cache.

Comment: I tested `127.0.0.1:3306` and cleared the cache after but this did not solve the problem

Comment: try surrounding the address with double quotes (_as showed in the docs_) like `DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/project"` (_and clear the cache_) PS: Did that line works before?

Comment: No, this is also not working. Only thing that is actually working is `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost/project` Are you sure, this is the correct port?

Comment: I can't know which port are you using for mysql :-) in fact I wrote "try adding the **used** port" (_3306 is the default one in local dev like, as example, XAMPP_)

Comment: Ah, yeah, the port was wrong. It is another number. But it is still not working... I think this number 127.0.0.1 is probably wrong too

Comment: Perhaps `root` user is allowed to use only `localhost`. Look at user's permission in phpmyadmin

Comment: There is  quite some number of questions related to this issue. What is the value of your `bind_address` parameter in `my.cnf`. And what does your computer resolve `localhost` to?

Comment: Also, this answer https://serverfault.com/a/845155/145904 explains how, from MySQL's perspective, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` might not be all the same, regardless of DNS configuration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the user permissions of the database itself, your user may only be allowed to access via localhost.

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user where user = '<username>';
```

check the host column. If you only get one row back with the host 'localhost' then you could add another with the same details but for the 127.0.0.1 host

```
CREATE USER '<username>'@'127.0.0.1';
SET PASSWORD FOR '<username>'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('<password>');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The sql is off the top of my head, you might need to double check it.