# Why does a DNS lookup take so long with a MySQL connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, dns

I was debugging some code and realised that a method was taking almost 2 seconds to connect to MySQL.  After a bit of digging ([Why is constructing PDO connection slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800577/why-is-constructing-pdo-connection-slow)) I found that it's because I was using 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1'.  This sped it up significantly.  My question is, why? Why does a lookup in my /etc/hosts take so long? I would've thought it was really quick. Also, this optimisation doesn't speed anything up on my work desktop, but definitely worked on my laptop (they're both running Ubuntu 12.04)

Edit: My question is **why** does it take so long. I understand that the comment in the linked question says that lookups take a long time, but I am asking **why**.

Comment: Isn't this answered in a comment on the question you already linked to?

Comment: It simply says that it takes too long, but my question is **why** does it take so long? There are few entries in my hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with sockets and the way MySQL treats `localhost`.  See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be more about the inverse resolution? Normally it is really a better idea to user "real" names and IPs, even if it is a local connection. Try using the hostname of the server and the IP.

Comment: What do you mean by inverse resolution?

Comment: When you translate a name to an IP address is direct resolution and when IP is translated to the name that is the reverse resolution (or inverse, I have read it in both ways). Some client-server comunications have delay issues when trying to check who is on the other side, by asking for the reverse resolution of the hostname that originated the conection. 127.0.0.1 is a special case and maybe it is not being translated to locahost. Thats one reason why I normally prefer real IPs and names.