# root@localhost can't connect to database through PHP (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to connect to my database through PHP for a few hours now, with no success. My PHP code looks like this:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    function testdb_connect($hostname, $username, $password) {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=asdf", $username, $password);
        return $db;
    }

    try {
        $db = testdb_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
        echo 'Connected to database';
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    ?>
```

What I have already tried:

- Checked if 'root' is configured to 'localhost' (Y)
- Checked if root@localhost has Grant_priv/Super_priv permissions (Y
  for both)
- Checked if Apache/MySQL is running (Y for both) Checked if my PHP
- Code is wrong, i.e. I am missing something (N)

Any ideas where the Problem could lie? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I am so sorry, I have seen the error message so often today, I forgot to mention it here:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

RE-EDIT:

Here the php code with the user I created:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'myUserName';
    $password = 'thatUserPassword';

    function testdb_connect($hostname, $username, $password) {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=asdf", $username, $password);
        return $db;
    }

    try {
        $db = testdb_connect($hostname, $username,    $password);
        echo 'Connected to database';
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
```

Error Message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myUserName'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Can you provide more info? What error are you getting?

Comment: without the exact error message, we are of little help.

Comment: have you tried to use `$hostname = '127.0.0.1';` instead of `'localhost'`? Some time ago I hat a problem related to this.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen — Forcing TCP/IP instead of using a local socket is more likely to cause problems than solve them, and is inefficient at best.

Comment: @Quentin is that you down voting all answers?

Comment: @Quentin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800577/why-is-constructing-pdo-connection-slow

Comment: @AbcAeffchen — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1

Comment: I guess @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ our answers must be couched so as to deal with every imaginable Advisory Responsibility or Caveat comment, thus making them so watered down and slow to produce, that by the time they arrive, the OP has succumbed to exhaustion. So this will be my next strategy. That is, answer with a battery of Lawyers at my side

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ  I wish someone accounted for such acts  x)

Comment: @Drew are you watching this? +2/-2 for both of us? I mean what's happening? whyy!

Comment: I could tell you @HawasKaPujaari but you probably wouldn't like the answer and it won't be typed here

Comment: @Drew but I really wanted to know *sigh

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari ... well I have an email address on my Profile Page. Then I will have to determine if it is really you :)

Comment: @Drew check your mail from emkay992. cheers

Comment: I have read nearly all other threads with the same question. None of them worked for me... @AbcAeffchen yes I have and I receive the same error message (it was 127.0.0.1 by default, then I changed it)

Answer (score 3):

Let's say I do this:

### A

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhostaaa;dbname=so_gibberish;charset=utf8', 'myUser', 'myPassword');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo "I am right here<br/>";
?>
```

Then upon errors, I get a white screen.

Let's say I do this:

### B

```
<?php
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhostxxxx;dbname=so_gibberish;charset=utf8', 'fred', 'password');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
    echo "You are connected<br/>";
?>
```

**Then B gives me connect error information**

### Edit:

Based on that edit to Question, please have a user created with a password, and pass that password, not a blank string.

It is important to not connect as root, as it is an admin account for maintenance. Using root exposes you to the risk of having scripts comprised and credentials stolen (if so baked-in and not in a `vault`), thus allowing a hacker to gain access to all your databases.

### Error:

```
[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Could be issues with `my.cnf` file and `bind-address` setting. Need to see that.

What I would suggest, is create a non-root user `'jimmy987'@'%'`, and do a

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'jimmy987'@'%'=PASSWORD('');
```

See if it works with that user, then drop the user. Note that the error message will change if successful, perhaps barking about no rights to use the database. Because the Grants were not performed.

Based on articles that seems to suggest the server is expecting a blank password.

Then we need to fix why.

Outside of that, I would have to do a TeamViewer session to see what is up (as I certainly don't see what you are really running). I would love to know the answer when you fix it.

Comment: I added the error message in the question now. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @Drew Yes that was my initial attempt.... However I received the same error message, although I granted that user all privileges.

Comment: P.S. Thats why I tried it with root, as I thought the problem might be user-based

Comment: there is this [article](http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/remove-anonymous-user-from-mysql/) about deleting Anonymous users

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4615   ... it would be good to know if this is the issue

Comment: I came across the exact same article xD Nope not an issue as a it still doesn't work after I set a password (and for the user I created with a password it didn't work either)

Comment: edit the question, show an error message for someone other than **root**. Gotta get away from root anyway

Comment: @Drew I just edited it. The error message stays the same.

Comment: @Drew Not sure if this is relevant but this code should run when a button on my website is pressed.

Comment: I would have to go into teamviewer and run various attempts against it. Best I can say. Some trickier problems are not solved in little text boxes down here.

Comment: *sigh* I just realised that I didn't create the database I wanted to access through my code on phpMyAdmin, but through my terminal. Hence the DB didn't even exist and thats why the error message. Fixed it now. Thank you for you help anyways!

Comment: hey Money, all is well that ends well bud :)

Comment: For me the problem was using root user :) thx for the info which solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not mention the *exact* errors, I'm afraid it'll be hard to guess for most of us. Try this for a change?

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "asdf";

try
{
 $db_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
 $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
 $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: who knows, we can't buy cheeseburgers with these points anyway. Just help and move on :)

Comment: I added the error message in the question now. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @MoneyIsAMotivation, you need to have/create a user with a password and then give the credentials instead of empty password string. or you could just change the password for root and give that password instead. read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari already tried that and it didn't work... (that was my initial attempt)