# PDO MySQL Connection close - unset vs null

Tags: php, pdo

I've read in PDO manual that to close connection you should use the following:

```
$connection = null;
```

However, Some people suggested that since PHP 5.3 has a new GC, the following should be used:

```
unset($connection);
```

I need to know once and for all, which one is preferred, or are they the same?

Comment: Why do you think you want it? Do you experience any particular problem at the moment, caused by this very dilemma?

Comment: Yes, too many connections cause my system to have low performance.
Before I undergo my entire loops I need to know how to change it correctly.

Comment: [Related...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444748/is-it-necessary-to-close-pdo-connections)

Comment: -1 for having more than one connection per script execution which is *apparently* awful for the system performance.

Comment: I don't have a choice when running multiple databases. -1 for giving -1 for no reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do the same thing. Unsetting the `$pdo` handle and setting it null both close the connection.

You can test this for yourself. Run the following script in one window, and in a second window open the MySQL client and run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` every couple of seconds to see when the connection disappears.

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO(..);
sleep(10);
unset($pdo);
echo "pdo unset!\n";
sleep(10);
```

Then change `unset($pdo)` to `$pdo=null;` and run the test again.

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO(..);
sleep(10);
$pdo = null;
echo "pdo set null!\n";
sleep(10);
```

The extra `sleep()` at the end is there to give you a moment to see that the connection has dropped, before the PHP script terminates (which would drop the connection anyway).

Comment: The only *small* difference I see is that `unset()` will destroy the variable. Which means `var_dump($pdo);` would throw an error `Undefined variable`.

Comment: @HamZa, thanks, that's true! I should say, they do the same thing *with respect to closing the database connection.*

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled with this.  I have a PDO object that spans setup and teardown, and I can't find where there must be a remaining reference, as setting $pdo to null did not resolve the problem.

User Contributed Notes in http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php discusses the problem of delayed closure.  Here they suggest killing the current connection:

$pdo->query('SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_backend_pid());');
$pdo = null;

This is for postgres.  For mysql I have used:

$pdo->query('KILL CONNECTION CONNECTION_ID();');

Answer (score -2):

using

```
$pdo = null; //is an assignment to null; the variable still declared in the memory.
```

but

```
unset($pdo); // will call the function to distroy also the adress "@" pointed by the variable.
```

so using unset is prefered.

Answer (score -6):

Just don't bother with closing at all. PHP will close it for you all right.

Note that of course your application have to be sanely designed, without the need of reconnecting to different databases at a rate of machine-gun. And even in latter case, the method you are using to close would be the least problem. You are barking wrongest tree ever. Work the number of connections, not the way you are closing them.

Comment: This is totally untrue, and very bad advice. Some php scripts are long-running, and need to fetch some data from a db before launching a long task, and you don't want to keep one connection slot open in sleep for nothing. There MUST be a proper way to close+free ANY resource in PHP: true for network, db connections, sockets or anything else.
Relying on the = null;  assignment is very wrong, IMHO.