# PHP - Static Local Variables

Tags: php, static

So I recently ran across a code segment like this:

```
private static function FOO() {
        static $c = null;
        if ($c == null) {
            $c = new ParentClass_InnerClass();
        }
        return $c;
    }
```

So what is up with this code? How is this different from:

```
private static $C;

//other methods and fields    

private static function FOO() {
    if(!$self::c) {
        $self::c = new ParentClass_InnerClass();
    }
    return $self::c;
}
```

Or are they even the same concept?

Comment: The second example is technically not correct. It should be `self::$c` or `static::$c`.

Comment: Read more at [PHP: Variable scope - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) about static local variables

Comment: @ComFreek Whoops, yep.

Comment: `$c == null` and `!$c` is not entirely the same thing, is it?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg How do you mean in this case? It's not like $c is ever going to be a boolean false. You are really nitpicking at a piece of code that is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @thatidiotguy It's still not correct :) `self::$c`, not `$self::c`.

Comment: @thatidiotguy True, didn't consider the usage of the variable `$c` in the question. I was thinking too much outside the box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are, essentially, the same concept, though the scope is different:

```
class Foobar
{
    private static $c = null;
    public static function FOO()
    {
        if (self::$c === null)
        {
            self::$c = new stdClass;
        }
        return self::$c;
    }
    public static function checkC()
    {
        if (self::$c === null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return self::$c;
    }
}

Foobar::checkC();//returns false, as $c is null
//function checkC has access to $c
$returned = Foobar::FOO();//returns object
if ($returned === Foobar::checkC())
{//will be true, both reference the same variable
    echo 'The same';
}
```

Whereas, if we were to change the code to:

```
class Foobar
{
    public static function FOO()
    {
        static $c = null;
        if ($c === null)
        {
            $c = new stdClass;
        }
        return $c;
    }
    public static function checkC()
    {
        if ($c === null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return $c;
    }
}
```

We will get a notice when calling `checkC`: undefined variable. the static variable $c is only accessible from within the `FOO` scope. A private property is scoped within the entire class. That's it really.
But really, do yourself a favour: only use statics if you need them (they're shared between instances, too). And in PHP, it's very rare you'll actually need a static.

Comment: Hi!
I get the difference, but I have to ask how come it doesn't reset $c = null on every call to FOO()?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @sale108 Haven't used PHP in 5 years, but a variable in a function declared as `static` creates a `zval` in memory with whatever value you assign to it in the declaration/initialisation statement. Whatever happens to that `zval` next updated the same object in memory. Essentially, think of `static $c = null;` as something that is executed once, and then skipped in subsequent calls

Comment: Thanks! That's enough for me to investigate on my own :)

Answer (score 7):

They're the same concept, except that in the first code block, the static variable is local to the function, and such a static variable could be used in any function, even outside the context of a class:

```php
function test() {
    static $counter = 0;
    return $counter++;
}

echo test(); // 0
echo test(); // 1
```

Comment: How? Its a private function. You mean another public function could pass the variable out?

Comment: No, this kind of variable is local to the function and cannot be used outside of it. I mean that you could use a static variable in any function, even if it's not a class method.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example in a simple function, outside of a class.

Answer (score 1):

In the top example you can access `$c` only from the local scope (`FOO()`) and in the bottom example you can access `$c` from the entire class, so not only form `FOO()`.

Comment: So its forcing the singleton pattern for a private variable, but since its forcing you to go through `FOO()` you are guaranteeing it is initialized?

Comment: @thatidiotguy: yes, but forcing a class to be initialized can be done using the Factory pattern, too, aswel as by _using a constructor, and the `new` keyword_ [Don't use singletons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564416/run-parent-non-static-function-from-singleton-childs-instance-property/19564563#19564563)