# PDO with a pool of reusable connections

Tags: php, database, pdo, database-connection, persistent-connection

I've created a class (called `DBPDO`) that **extends the standard PDO** class (`class DBPDO extends PDO {}`) in order to have all the methods and properties that come with PDO with the addition of more control on the queries (ie. profiling when developing, etc...) and methods that permit to speed up the work when coding queries.

I'd like to improve this class. I'm thinking about all the connections that are created throughout the website, most of all are created inside different scopes to perform independent queries. So I'm wondering: why do I have to create ie. 5 connections on 5 different methods/classes/functions of my application, when I could use the same connection on all of them?

I don't want to use persistent connections (for example read [What are the disadvantages of using persistent connection in PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332074/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-persistent-connection-in-pdo)).

I'd just like to have a class that - when instantiated - gives me an already active connection, if exists, or gives me a new one.
There is a problem, though. What if I have to visit the results of a query and perform another query at each result? I necessarily need two different connections. So I'll need to tell this new class if I want a brand new connection or a used one.

I was thinking of writing a new class `PDOConn`, with an static method `getConnection($forceNew = false) {}` and an static private property `$Connections = array()`.

When I need a connection, I write:

```
$dbh = PDOConn::getConnection();
```

PDOConn will look if `$Connections` already contains at least one connection (in form of an instance of my already working `DBPDO` class) and reaturns that object. If `$Connections` is empty, it will create a new object (instance of `DBPDO`), adds that object to `$Connections` and returns it.

If I want to force the creation of a new connection, I'll write:

```
$dbh = PDOConn::getConnection(true);
```

So it will create a new connection and adds it to `$Connections`. When `getConnection` is called again without forcing a new creation, `PDOConn` will return the first created connection (or maybe the last one?).

**Questions**
Do you think this is a good way, a good idea? Do you have any better suggestion? Most of all: do you think that there's something I didn't consider in my `PDOConn` class functionality that could cause me problems I'm not figuring out right now? Do you think that writing a class like that is worthy to manage PDO connections? I mean, I started this thread because I wanted to reuse connections when it's not necessary to create new ones: is this worthy/relevant or I can continue creating how many connections I want, it doesn't matter?

Thank you.

Comment: This may be worth a read http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16201/php-mysql-persistent-connection-pooling-without-mysql-pconnect-possible  I'm not entirely sure you can do pooling with pdo like you suggest without using some form of middleware to do the actual pool+persistance and you just query the middle ware.

Comment: Just done a little digging and this seems like quite a nice solution to the issue http://gonzalo123.com/2012/05/21/database-connection-pooling-with-php-and-react-node-php/  needs refinement but it seems like a pretty good approach to it

Comment: Thank you for your comments... Anyway I want to stay on PDO for many reasons, both personal and projects-related, so I'll try to find out a solution with a look to the links you posted.