# Deprecated: mysql_pconnect()

Tags: php, html, mysql

Keep getting this line now when i run my sql query:

> Deprecated: mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\Users\Murray\Desktop\YouthCafeWork\BookingSystem\bookingrequest.php on line 43

I have tried to change it so that it is using the new syntax but i can not get it to work.

Line 43 (the error line is) is :

```
$db = mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'root', '');
```

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Did you have looked at the [red box](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)?

Comment: Did you read the error message? "*use mysqli or PDO instead*"

Comment: I suggest adding the code you *tried* instead that you couldn't get working. Note you need to replace all the code that works with your DB, not just the `connect` statement.

Comment: yes i did read the red box and yes i did read the error message. I am just unsure of how to use mysqli?

Comment: `mysqli_connect() with p: host prefix` is pretty straight forward.

Comment: The entire `mysql` extension is deprecated, not just that one function. You need to recode everything using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation of [mysql_pconnect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) is stating, you should use `mysqli_connect()` with p: host prefix:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('p:localhost', 'root', '');
```

Comment: Better yet: drop the _persistent_ bit all together... a stateless language, like PHP, and a persistent connection doesn't make much sense. [there are disadvantages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332074/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-persistent-connection-in-pdo) to consider

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use either `mysqli` or `PDO` for your database connections.

you should read on [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

PDO connections are done this way

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

mysqli connection is done this way

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Answer (score 0):

support from php for mysql has been deprecated and will be removed very soon so the warning is displayed.
use this- 
object oriented style -

`$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");
$mysqli->select_db("world");`

or Procedural style

`$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");mysqli_select_db($link, "world");`

Comment: Yes, and this is what the question says, so you're not adding anything useful.

Answer (score -3):

As you can see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php

mysql_pconnect function is deprecated. Insted of use this function, use: mysqli_connect

For more info, see: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

and:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

EDIT:

Try this (if you did not set a root password for your mysql server):

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', NULL, 'dabase_name');
```

Regards
PS

Comment: Answers with links to solutions aren't a good format for SO. Try answering the question directly using links as a supporting. (dv wasn't me)

Comment: Please try to provide links to the official PHP documentation, and *especially* not W3Schools.

Comment: Dear @DavidBarker 

I Answers commenting.

I use the link only for her references. What is wrong with that? Is the same to post a Book Title Reference

Comment: yeah i have tried to do this at the moment i am using `$db = mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'root', '');` and i have tried to change this to the mysqli way `$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root");` is this correct, i think it needs the root password and db name but i do not know what the password is as i have not needed it before?

Comment: [SO: How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) `[...]Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.[...]`

Comment: @FallingStar what error did you receaved ? 

You MySQL server have a root password setted up ?

If not, try this:

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', NULL, 'database_name');