# Multiple Ajax calls with mysql and session variables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, session

I wrote a portal for my company that has dozens of ajax calls in it.  For every ajax call, the target script uses mysql and session variables.  on every one of those scripts I do:

page.php

```
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:someData,
            url:target.php,
            success:function(result){
                    someAction
            }
    });
```

target.php

```
   <?php
      session_start(); 
      //target from ajax.php
      require_once('/var/www/lib/db.php');
       ......
       ......
        $_SESSION['someVar'] = $someMysqlResult;
```

db.php

```
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=someDB', 'someUser', 'somePassword');
```

so I am setting up new mysql connections dozens of times.  Is there a better way?  Is there a mysql resource I can carry across all of these ajax calls?

I am also starting the session dozens of times.  Is there a better way to open the session again on the target script?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), you can use persistent connections:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

> Many web applications will benefit from making persistent connections to database servers. Persistent connections are not closed at the end of the script, but are cached and re-used when another script requests a connection using the same credentials. The persistent connection cache allows you to avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection every time a script needs to talk to a database, resulting in a faster web application.

You should be aware that doing this though has some negative drawbacks to be aware of: [What are the disadvantages of using persistent connection in PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332074/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-persistent-connection-in-pdo)