# PHP - Best way to connect to database when there are multiple connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

I have just recently acquired the service side of a medium size project. The former developer has all of his functions as separate php scripts instead of classes (func1.php, func2.php, etc)... All these 'functions' make a reference to `mysqli_connect` via referencing the actual
'databaseonnection.php' file. This is creating a new connection every time any of the scripts run (every time I have to call a function) and I don't want to do that. I was thinking about having a persistent connection, but I'm worried about it getting out of hands as the project is growing more and more every day. So, has anyone ever encountered a  similar situation? What is the best way to handle my connection to the database? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `mysql_*` Functions deprecated.Use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Comment: the original approach sounds 'normal' are you sure you know the implications of the changes you suggest?

Comment: @Dagon I dont want to open a new connection every time I have to call a function...

Comment: that's normal, and connectors are reused. i worry if what you want is not normal practice, you need to understand why.

Comment: @Dagon The ideal solution would be to implement all the functions in classes, so only the class would call the connection, not every single function. I don't have time for doing that right now, so I was wondering if there is a way around it.

Comment: a little knowledge is a dangerous thing ;(

Comment: persistent connections are generally a bad idea for php scripts. very easy to get yourself into a database deadlock situation.

Comment: @Dagon what do you mean? I've always had a class type approach through my career.

Comment: i mean your suggesting a really bad approach

Comment: @Dagon How do you mean? Whats wrong with referencing functions from classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs for [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned.

Comment: Thanks. That had gone over my head!

Comment: Keep in mind that `mysql_connect()` was depreciated as of php version 5.5.0 and was removed in version 7.0.0. Use `mysqli_connect()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I'm sorry I thought you wanted connectivity help. There is no way except to move all those "functions" into one file where the connection is for them only.

I create a con.php file where my PDO connection is established then include that file anywhere you wish to use a connection Here is the base for a PDO connection:

```
$PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", "user_name", "password");
```

Here is my notes on using the PDO object to make prepared queries. There is more than you need below but good luck.

Within your PHP file that needs a connection:
        1:      include('con.php');

```
2:  $datas = $PDO->prepare(SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE :searchquery);
    // prepare method creates and returns a PDOstatment object ( print_r($datas); ) which contains an execute() method
    // PDOstatment object has its own methods ie. rowCount()

    // $datas->bindValue(':search', '% . $search . %', )
    // Optional - Manually bind value. see http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

3: $datas->execute( array(':searchquery' => $searchquery . '%'));
    // pass in values that need to be bound AND EXECUTE.

    // There are 17 ways to "fetch" data with the PDO object.
4: $datas-fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

close a pdo connection by the handle:

```
$PDO = null;
```

Comment: Yes but you have to redesign the entire project unless you're going to use a very outdated database connection function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be much better off using `PDO` as opposed to the old `MYSQL` functions e.g. `mysql_connect`. It's much more robust an interface.

Below is the basic code to do this:

```
$db_handle = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_host.";dbname=".$db_name.";port=".$db_port."", $db_username, $db_password, $connect_options);
```

where `$db_handle` is the PDO object representing the database connection, `$db_host` is your hostname [usually localhost], `$db_name` is the name of your database, `$db_port` is the database port number [usually 3306], `$db_username` and `$db_password` are your database user access credentials, and `$connect_options` are optional driver-specific connection options.

To enable persistent connections you need to set the driver-specific connection option for it before opening the connection: `$connect_options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);` then execute the earlier database connection code.

You can get more information on this from the PHP Docs here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php.

Regarding creating persistent connections, I would suggest that you close every database connection you open at the end of your script (after all your database operations of course) by nullifying your database handle: `$db_handle = NULL;`. You should do this whether you opened a persistent connection or not. It sounds counter-intuitive, but I believe you should free up any database resources when your script is done.

The performance disadvantages of doing this [from my experience] are neglible for most applications. This is obviously an arguable assertion and you may also find the following link helpful in further clarifying your strategy in this regard:

> [Persistent DB Connections - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303/persistent-db-connections-yea-or-nay)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

if you have very complex project and need big budget to re-design, and prefer very simple alteration then

1) stay in mysqli_connect
2) move the database connection to header of your script. 
3) remove the function databse close() on that functions.
4) remove the connection link variables, it wont needed for single database.
5) close the database on end of footer.

By this way, database connection establish when starting your script and after all queries, it will be closed on footer. your server can handle the connections without closing/re-open by using keepalive method. basically default keepalive value is 30 to 90 seconds.