# Too many connections for single php file when hit multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, mysqli

I am trying to run a php file through shell script multiple times.

I open connection like this (**index.php**).

```
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database')
```

I got following error

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1040): Too many connections

I could increase `max_connections` in mysql `my.cnf` file. But I think this is not a good idea because it slows things down.

Here is my .sh file code when I run. It hits php file 750 times

```
#!/bin/bash

max=750
for i in `seq 0 $max`
do
    php index.php $i &
done
```

Can I share one connection across a file when it is hit simultaneously? Or is there any better approach?

Any Help?

Comment: Show us the source code of the page showing the error.

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224001/how-to-share-a-mysql-connection-between-2-different-php-processes

Comment: Updated question @CoderDudeTwodee

Comment: You're either creating the connection twice or more in the same page or their is a server misconfiguration (less likely).

Comment: Max connections defaults to 151 according to the mysql manual.  So you are likely hitting that.  Echo $max to see when the error occurs.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

Comment: @Progrock Yeah I was able to solve this as I explained in my question by increasing connection. My real question is that can I share one connection across same file running multiple times?

Comment: Could you add some more context to the question.  Do you really need to background those processes?  What are you doing?