# Laravel createConnection Timing Out

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

Recently I started using New Relic to profile my application and I  came across something peculiar.  Every once and a while my application would hang for 15-20 seconds and then fail.  Digging in I found that the createConnection method to the percona mysql was timing out in my Laravel5 application.

Here is the offending method in the Laravel5 source: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php#L48-L63

Here is a picture of the transaction trace that is failing: 
[image: Transaction Trace with createConnection hang]

There are two instances running the same application in my stack.  Each one does about 100-400 calls per minute to the database depending on if the load balancer is pointing to that particulatr instance.

I'm wondering if there is a way to stop this from happening.  Some ideas that I had:

- Turn on persistent connections for the PDO connection.
- Change a MySQL setting, not sure which.  (Let me know if you want to see the current options).
- Set PHP to timeout after 5 seconds to stop the current connection.

Ideas and thoughts are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimenting I came to the conclusion that turning on Persistent Connections in our MySQL PDO connection was the answer.  I had a alot of reservations about turning them on based upon what I had read.  But after reading this post: [Persistent DB Connections - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303/persistent-db-connections-yea-or-nay/51583#51583) and Steve Corona's book "[Scaling PHP Applications](https://www.scalingphpbook.com/)", that turning on persistent connections was the way to go.