# One mysqli connection for multiple database functions

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, mysqli

My main page calls many database functions, stored in the db.php file. In each of them, I'm connecting to the MySQL database using

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(SERVER_NAME,SERVER_USER,SERVER_PASS,SERVER_DB);
```

and then after some queries, I'm closing it with

```
mysqli_close($connect);
```

No problem so far. But I want to know is there any way to make the code faster, by executing the connection just one time in the main code, at top of all DB function calls? and then closing the connection at the bottom of the main code?

In other words, How to access a variable (here *$connect*) which is outside of a function, without having to pass it as a parameter to that certain function?

I tried declaring *$connect* as **global** or **static** But none of them worked.

Comment: you dont need to explicitly close the connection in most cases.

Comment: @smith good to know thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persistent DB Connections - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303/persistent-db-connections-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the connection in the function and call it when needed.

---

Create db.php;

```
function connect(){
    $conn = @mysqli_connect(SERVER_NAME,SERVER_USER,SERVER_PASS);
    mysqli_select_db($conn, SERVER_DB);
    return $conn;
}
function close_connect($conn){
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Use:

```
require_once "db.php";
$conn = connect();
// excute query
close_connect($conn);
```

Comment: But the point is I wanna access $conn directly in my queries, which are inside functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
<?php

$conn=xxx;


function abc() {

global $conn->.....;
} 



$conn=null;
```

this is not the best way of doing it. You should look at OOP practices with singleton pattern.